# Issue with sapply when determining if nested list has all NA values in R

Tags: r

I have a nested list (or list of lists) with NA randomly allocated values. I am trying to determine if the nested list contains all `NA` values. For example:

```
#Example list with NA values
L.miss<-list(list(NA,NA,c(NA,NA,NA),c(NA,NA)),list(1,6,c(0,3,NA,0,NA,0),c(0,NA,0,1,0,0),1,NA,c(0,1),2,c(0,0)),
             list(NA,NA),list(1,0),list(1,NA,c(NA,0,0,0),c(NA,NA),c(1,0,0,NA,0),0))
```

Here, `L.miss[[1]]` and `L.miss[[3]]` contain all `NA` values. When I try:

```
all.NA<-sapply(L.miss, function(x) all(is.na(x)))
```

it returns a logical vector `[1] FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE`. The desired output would be `[1] TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE` since positions `L.miss[[1]]` and `L.miss[[3]]` contain vectors of all `NA`. I have tried `lapply` and `rapply` in the same function but does not work, and an exhaustive internet search doesn't provide much help. I am not sure why it is picking up the `[[3]]` position and not the `[[1]]` position. Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

unlist the nested lists, then test:

```
all.NA<-sapply(L.miss, function(x) all(is.na(unlist(x))))
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to apply `all(is.na())` to the nested lists:

```
all.NA <- sapply(L.miss, function(x) all(sapply(x, function(y) all(is.na(y)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

According to `?is.na`:

> The default methods also work for lists and pairlists: For 'is.na',  elementwise the result is false unless that element is a length-one atomic vector and the single element of that vector is regarded as 'NA' or 'NaN' (note that any 'is.na' method for the class of the element is ignored). 'anyNA(recursive = FALSE)' works the same way as 'is.na'; 'anyNA(recursive = TRUE)' applies 'anyNA' (with method dispatch) to each element

So, the element `c(NA, NA)` of your list will always return `FALSE`. To achieve your desired result, you need to apply `is.na` to each element of the nested atomic vector.
.